# How to avoid that Pepper Robot recognizes the same Landmark more times?

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

By reason of developing a module to do the self-localization I need to build a python box in Choreragphe which helps to avoid that Pepper Robot recognizes the same Landmark more times. *The original landmark is only responsible for detecting the landmark but repeats the process for the same landmark.*
My basic idea is to build a string including the numbers of the recognized landmarks. But in Choreragphe if we do this based on getting values of the AlMemory module; the variables would be refreshed every time when a landmark is detected regardless of if it’s new. (Please see picture 1)
[image: ChoregrapheLandmarkDetection]
This code

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
def __init__(self):
    GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
    #put initialization code here
    self.markIDs = []
    moreInfo = []
    self.memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")
    # Connect the event callback.
    # Get the services ALMotion & ALRobotPosture.
    self.motion_service = ALProxy("ALMotion")
    # Get the services ALTextToSpeech, ALLandMarkDetection and ALMotion.
    self.motion_service = ALProxy("ALMotion")
    self.got_landmark = False

def onLoad(self):
    self.logger.debug("Loaded box %s", self.getName())

def onUnload(self):
    #puts code for box cleanup here
    pass

def onInput_onStart(self, p):
    markIDs = []
    moreInfo = []
    # Generic Extractor output format:
    # p = [ [timeStampMaj, timeStampMin], [ tag0, tag1, ... tagN] ] with tag = [ shapeInfo, moreInfo ]
    if(len(p) > 0)&(not (moreInfo in markIDs)):
        self.logger.info("moreInfo in markIDs=")
        self.logger.info((moreInfo in markIDs))
        markInfoArray = p[1]
        self.logger.info("markInfoArray =")
        self.logger.info(markInfoArray)
        for markInfo in markInfoArray:
            moreInfo = markInfo[1]
            # moreInfo = [ landmarkID ]
            self.logger.info("markInfo =")
            self.logger.info(str(markInfo))
            self.logger.info("moreInfo=")
            self.logger.info(str(moreInfo))
            if not (moreInfo[-1] in markIDs):
                self.got_landmark = True
            markIDs.append(moreInfo[-1])
            self.logger.info("markIDs =")
            self.logger.info(str(markIDs))

    self.onStopped(markIDs)
```

gives this result back:

```
    [INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:30 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo in markIDs= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:31 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: False 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:34 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfoArray = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:35 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[[1, 0.18835650384426117, 0.14215253293514252, 0.12947072088718414, 0.12947072088718414, 16], [84]]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:40 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfo = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:41 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[1, 0.18835650384426117, 0.14215253293514252, 0.12947072088718414, 0.12947072088718414, 16], [84]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:42 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:43 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:49 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markIDs = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:22 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/ProcessMarksList_2: p[0] =  
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:23 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/ProcessMarksList_2: 84 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:51 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:30 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo in markIDs= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:31 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: False 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:34 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfoArray = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:40 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfo = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:42 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:35 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[[1, 0.18835650384426117, 0.14215253293514252, 0.12947072088718414, 0.12947072088718414, 16], [84]]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:49 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markIDs = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:43 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:41 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[1, 0.18835650384426117, 0.14215253293514252, 0.12947072088718414, 0.12947072088718414, 16], [84]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:51 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:30 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo in markIDs= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:31 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: False 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:34 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfoArray = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:41 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[1, 0.08169912546873093, 0.14497141540050507, 0.12635093927383423, 0.12635093927383423, 17], [84]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:35 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [[[1, 0.08169912546873093, 0.14497141540050507, 0.12635093927383423, 0.12635093927383423, 17], [84]]] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:43 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84] 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:42 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: moreInfo= 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:49 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markIDs = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:40 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: markInfo = 
[INFO ] behavior.box :onInput_onStart:51 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11241679648:/NAOMark_3/Get Marks List_1: [84]
```

But if we do this in a python script alone, and then import it to Choregraphe, at that point I was suggested to follow the workflow in the Github project of Mr.Emile,[robot-jumpstarter](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter) which I have tried but failed to make it work in Choregraphe.

***Thus,is it possible to do some local python script in Choregraphe (like it in picture3)parallel to the Naomark  module to save the detected MarkID in that and so on*** ?
[image: ChoregrapheNaoMark]

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps don't catch the difficulty, anyway it seems very simple to tackle:
add a box connected to the output of DetectLandmark and do this kind of code:

```
def onInput( self, p ):
  if p != self.last
    self.last = p
    self.output(p)
```

Comment: Yep, I have already solved my problem by writing somthing like your suggestion in "Process Markslist" box and forgot to delete this question......  I was confused because I only thought about writing things in "GetMarksList" box... thanks anyway :)